# How do I call a helper function to calculate percentiles by unique identifiers using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, quantile, percentile

I have a dataset that shows unique ID and a numerical metric called "hardened_print_length". I am storing the unique IDs and metrics in a Pandas dataframe and need to calculate percentiles (exclusive) by each unique ID (50th percentile, 75th, 95th). I am using the following helper function:

```
def quantile_exc(ser, q):
     ser_sorted = ser.sort_values()
     rank = q * (len(ser) + 1) - 1
     assert rank > 0, 'quantile is too small'
     rank_l = int(rank)
     return ser_sorted.iat[rank_l] + (ser_sorted.iat[rank_l + 1] - 
                                 ser_sorted.iat[rank_l]) * (rank - rank_l)
```

Calling Function (percentile_staging is a two column dataframe storing the unique ID as a string and the hardened_print_length as a decimal):

```
def test(percentile_staging):
df = pd.DataFrame(percentile_staging)
head = df.head()
print(head)
fifty = quantile_exc(percentile_staging,.5)
```

df.head() results:

```
     pm_lookup                    hardened_print_length
0  2.4.1Printland Slab 2                  None
1  2.4.1Printland Slab 2                  None
2  2.4.1Printland Slab 2                  None
3  2.4.1Printland Slab 2                  None
4  2.4.1Printland Slab 2                  None
```

ERROR CODE:

```
TypeError: _get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'
```

I believe my issue is that I am storing the data as a DataFrame and the helper function uses a series to calculate the percentile. I am wondering if there is a solution to this error. I am uncertain on how to make each unique ID associated with a specific series, and then return the percentiles by project ID.

Comment: The indentation isn't correct.

Comment: Hi Jai127 can i see how do you call that function on your main file?

Comment: @zousan I added the code snippet for my call function

Comment: Yes but i want to see the implementation

Comment: Also the error says 'NoneType' , so maybe the problem isn't in your function expecting series but indeed the given res is incorrect

Comment: @zousan I am uncertain what you mean by implementation. I am using Palantir Foundry, which let's me write helper functions to a "Global Repository" and allows me to call it in any code block within my workbook.

Comment: @zousan I tried to cast the hardened_print_length as a integer but still returning same error code

Comment: I see, so i suspect the problem is on the dataset?

Comment: Can you do print the dataset by `df.head()` or something and show it to me if its work?

Comment: @zousan added it to the main post

Comment: @Jai127 All right, which column on that dataset that is the unique IDS, the pm lookup? Also there are still many possible errors i can think. Can you post code snippet from the beginning you load the dataset to when you call `def test()` ? sorry if i ask a lot

Comment: @zousan yes pm_lookup is the unique ID. In terms of loading dataset to def test(); I am cleaning the dataset to two columns using SQL prior to using Pandas.

Comment: @zousan I do not think it is an error from loading the dataset as all of my SQL compiles. For all purposes we can treat the dataframe with pm_lookup (unique ID) and hardened_print_length (actual data) as the singular "source".

Comment: So there is no preprocessing after you load the dataset? Try Replace the `ser_sorted = ser.sort_values()` with `ser_sorted = ser.sort_values('pm_lookup')` ?

Comment: @zousan A DataFrame object does not have an attribute sort_values. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.

When I implemented your adjustments I got this error

Comment: @Jai127 That is weird, let me check it

Comment: @Jai127 Try replace `sort_values` with `sort`

Comment: @zousan same error, just saying sort instead of sort_values

Comment: @Jai127 Try replace `fifty = quantile_exc(percentile_staging,.5)` with `fifty = quantile_exc(df,.5)` ?

Comment: @zousan I changed it back to ser_sorted = ser.sort_values('pm_lookup') and it's returning: TypeError: _get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'. Referencing row 10 of quantile_exc

Comment: Which row is the 10th row?

Comment: @zousan it's the last row of the helper function

Comment: I see, so now the errors is on the quantile formula you wrote, spesifically the `iat` attribute. I am sorry i'm not really familiar with `iat` but you can just return the sorted dataframe first and then experiment with it to try if the quantile formula is correct or not. At least now we know that there is no problem when calling helper function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.